# Minimal cd missing option for Minimal Ubuntu Desktop install

Tags: 18.04, system-installation

There is a minimal Lubuntu, Mate, Kubuntu, Xubuntu and so on but no minimal Ubuntu Desktop installation

[image: ubuntu 18.04 netboot/mini.iso]

Comment: For your information - I have reported [bug 1816288](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1816288) about 18.04 LTS and 18.10. But upcoming 19.04 has *Ubuntu minimal desktop* in *mini.iso* (or in `tasksel`).

Answer (score 5):

For minimal install, you have to choose the normal install, and during installation it offers the choice of minimum install.

[image: minimal installation option in ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso]

In fact, everything is installed first and in the end, it removes most of the things necessary to make Ubuntu run. For details, have a look at: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/02/ubuntu-18-04-minimal-install-option